# Computing the de Rham Cohomology of $\mathbb{S}^2$ using Cech Cohomology

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology

This might be a naïve question but I have decided to give it a try as I cannot figure out a way to give it a satisfactory answer.

I've learned about de Rham's theorem relating de Rham and Cech cohomology. Now I would like to see a direct application of this "algorithm" in the contest of compact manifolds, for example in the case of $\mathbb{S}^2$ (I was going to write $\mathbb{S}^n$, but let us keep this down to earth), to get a feeling of how one constructs a simple/good/admissible cover and then computes the Cech cohomology.

Does someone know any good (explicit) reference for this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The standard reference is Bott/Tu *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: Thank you! It contains exactly what I needed. (pp. 101-102 if anyone is interested)